# Strange keyboard behavior occurring in iOS11 during transition

Tags: ios, keyboard

In a view controller, I have a view, `paddingView`. I am transitioning to another view, `categoryView`, when an event occurs (button is pressed), and this transition is of type `UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight`.  Previously, this worked wonderfully.  However, in the iOS11 (im using 11.1), the keyboard seems to jump when this animation occurs.

```
//viewDidLoad
titleTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

fileprivate func flipViewToRight() {
    //transitionTextField is an off screen textfield, used to keep keyboard up during transition
    transitionTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    UIView.transition(from: paddingView, to: self.categoryView!, duration: 0.8, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> () in            
        self.categoryView?.searchTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    })
}
```

And this is the behavior that occurs:  https://youtu.be/31xNqBMi-BI

Is this a bug with iOS11?  It only seems to occur when this transition is occurring.

**Also:  The keyboard is always open on this view controller, there is always a textfield that is a first responder, before `titleTextField`, during `transitionTextField`, and after `self.categoryView?.searchTextfield` the flip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to resign the active textfield before activating another one, this seemed to fix the issue:

```
taskTitleTextView.resignFirstResponder()
transitionTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```